# using oneOf with shared elements in a property object

Tags: yaml, jsonschema

This is the YAML file i want to validate with a JSON schema. I am having some trouble getting the compiler type to support oneOf to select one of the compiler `gnu`, `intel`with shared field `source`. I am bit confused how oneOf works inside a properties field where each element in oneOf is also a property.

```
version: 0.0.1
hello_world_gnu:
  type: compiler
  module:
     - "module purge && module load gcc/4.0"
     - "module purge && module load gcc/6.0"
  compiler:
    source: src/hello.c
    gnu:
      cflags: -O1

hello_world_intel:
  type: compiler
  module:
   -  "module purge &&  module load intel/17"
   -  "module purge &&  module load intel/18"
  compiler:
    source: src/hello.c
    intel:
     cflags: -O1
```

The schema i have so far is the following

```
{
  "$id": "https://buildtesters.github.io/schemas/compiler/compiler-v0.0.1.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "BuildTest Schema for compiler",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["type", "compiler"],
  "propertyNames": {
    "pattern": "^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$"
  },
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^compiler$"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "module": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "compiler": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "source": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "gnu": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/compiler"
            },
            "intel": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/compiler"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "compiler": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "cflags": {"type":  "string"},
        "ldflags": {"type": "string"}
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `"pattern": "^compiler$"` you may want to use `"const": "compiler"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oneOf` inside `properties` results in a property with that name to be expected. But since you don’t want a `oneOf` property, you‘d have to move it up to the same level as `properties`. That being said, it’s usually better to declare all properties in a single place. And then only describe additional rules what is expected when.

One possibility is to declare all allowed properties and then use `dependencies` to ensure that the alternative properties are not allowed to be present at the same time.

```
    "compiler": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "source": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "gnu": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/compiler"
        },
        "intel": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/compiler"
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "gnu": {
          "not“: { "required": ["intel"] }
        },
        "intel": {
           "not“: { "required": ["gnu"] }
        }
      }
    }
```

If the `gnu`/`intel` properties are required, you could also use `oneOf`, e.g. like this:

```
    "compiler": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "source": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "gnu": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/compiler"
        },
        "intel": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/compiler"
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "required": ["gnu"]
        },
        {
          "required": ["intel"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it working with the second example. Yes i needed one of the compiler ``gnu`` or ``intel`` required so oneOf did the trick.

Comment: You can indicate the answer that solved your problem by selecting the tick mark on the left. Feel free to do that then.